# Import simplification doesn't work on Mac M1: Symbol not found. Expected in: flat namespace

Tags: python-3.x, macos, tensorflow, simplification, mini-forge

I have been trying to install `simplification` in a miniforge environment on a Mac M1 Big Sur but was not able to do so. I get the following error while importing `from simplification.cutil import simplify_coords_vwp` -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/akashyadav/miniforge3/envs/xview_env_tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/simplification/cutil.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _drop_float_array
  Referenced from: /Users/akashyadav/miniforge3/envs/xview_env_tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/simplification/cutil.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Users/akashyadav/miniforge3/envs/xview_env_tensor/lib/python3.8/site-packages/simplification/cutil.cpython-38-darwin.so
```

The installation works while directly installing from anaconda however. I need to use a miniforge environment to be able to use tensorflow on my machine

Answer (score 0):

First try installing the `simplification` package in your `MAC OS miniforge environment.`

```
pip install simplification
```

Then import the package to use:

```
from simplification.cutil import simplify_coords_vwp
```

You can find more detailed information to install `simplification` package in Mac OS [here](https://pypi.org/project/simplification/).
 Let us know if issue still persists.